# Inserting the URL for the Submitted InfoPath Form's to the Body of the Auto Generated Email from a Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, sharepoint-email

I want to create an workflow that is based on SharePoint 2013 List. I am OK with creating the workflow and triggering it once an item is created or modified.

In the Email alert it should contains the URL to the submitted InfoPath Form.

If compared with SharePoint 2010 workflows and SharePoint 2013 workflows which one is the best to use.

I cannot understand how to manipulate the URL to be dynamically changed from one submitted form to another.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

In the workflow Email windows there is a button with an icon of the earth and a part of a chain.

Click on that and type the text you want to display and as the address click on the 'Function - fx' and select 'Workflow Context' as the 'Data Source' and 'Current Item URL' as the 'Field from Source'

Click OK
Click OK

and that's it.
Chiranthaka